# how to change the footnote text color in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, context

The default color of footnote texts is black, if I want to change it into red, how can I achieve this?

I have used the

```
\setupfootnotes
  [textcolor=red]
```

or

```
\setupfootnotes
  [foregroundcolor=red]
```

or

```
\def\myfootnotetextcolor#1{%
  \startcolor[red]#1\stopcolor}
\setupfootnotes
  [textcommand={\myfootnotetextcolor}]
```

either method has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\setupnotation` command with `footnote` as argument. Example:

```
\setupnotation[footnote][color=red]

\starttext
  Some text
  \startfootnote
    and a footnote
  \stopfootnote
\stoptext
```

Comment: thanks, Marco. You always know the `how-to`.

Comment: but why I can't find this command in the ConTeXt wiki except that in the introduction of `footnote`?

Comment: The footnote mechanism was changed about a year ago, which required modifications to the user interface. Unfortunately no one updated the wiki to reflect the changes.

Comment: \setupnotation causes "Undefined control sequence"