# ConTeXt: Change the default text colour for entire document

Tags: color, context, context-mkiv, document-configuration

## Background

I am looking to change the text colour for a document from black to a different dark colour.

## Problem

The [documentation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Color) shows how to change individual colours for a text document, but does not show how to change the base black colour. This includes  body text, page numbers, footnotes, headings, table of contents, indices, bibliographies, and so forth.

However, changing the base text colour should not preclude overriding the text colour later on (e.g., to change the heading colour). I would like to override *every* aspect that uses the default black without having to *know* or *program* each aspect individually.

## Code

The following fails to set the footnote colour and the table border colour -- and there might be other aspects that use the default black that I don't know about:

```
\setupcolors[textcolor=red]
\setupinmargin[color=red] 

\starttext
\completecontent

\section{A test}
\inmargin{a test}

\placetable{Caption}
{\bTABLE
\bTR \bTD One \eTD \bTD two \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD One \eTD \bTD two \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE}

\input tufte

\section{Another test}
\index{test}Test footnotes\footnote[f]{A footnote test.} and \seeindex{test}{index}indexes.

\page
\placeindex

\stoptext
```

## Question

How do you change the default base black colour throughout the entire document, without having to configure all aspects individually?

## Note

ConTeXt should use a single colour that all text inherits. It should then be possible to change that single instance to ensure the new base colour is applied consistently throughout the document.

## Related

- https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg71123.html
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Color

Comment: There is no single interface, I'm afraid. So you'll have to set up each text item individually. That having said, it might be possible to inject the colour information into the font (using Lua). There are font colorschemes, but they don't automatically apply to each text item, which is no better than what you already have. Maybe a wizard comes up with something creative, I'm curious, too.

Comment: @Marco: Of course there is a simple interface. This is ConTeXt we are talking about :)

Comment: @Aditya You're right, there's an interface, but I couldn't get it working, see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ConTeXt mkii you need to specify `\setupcolors[state=start]`. If on the other hand, you are using ConTeXt mkiv, and want to specify a color for the margin, it must be set in the options of said margin, or else it will reset to default. So the margin is set with `\setupinmargin[color=red]`

The example that follows is with whatever color you want in the document, while keeping the page numbering color.

The second option, which I assume that based in your comment is what you want, will let you specify the color for the whole document.

The third option is with ConTeXt mkiv.

The fourth option is with ConTeXt mkiv in which the margin is set throughout the document by `\setupinmargin[line=13]`

The fifth example will show you that footnotes are also possible. 
In the following, we will use ConTeXt mkii to set footnotes throughout the document. To do so, the footnotes must be enclosed within an environment which is set with the command `\placelocalfootnotes` or else the footnotes won't appear in the document.

The sixth example is also with ConTeXt mkii, in which the `\color` command will take over. This time around the `\color` is grouped within the footnote, while the footnote is set in the preamble of the document. The option `state=start` must be specified, as well as the `color` option for the margin.

```
\setupinmargin[location=right,style=slanted,color=red]
\setupcolors[state=start]
\starttext
\startcolor[red] 
\section{A test}
\inmargin{Just a test}
\input tufte 
\input zapf    

\section{Another test}

\input knuth   
a test 
\dorecurse{2}{\input zapf \par \input tufte} 
\stoptext
```

[image]

```
\setupinmargin[location=right,style=slanted,color=red]
\setupcolors[state=start,textcolor=red]
\starttext

\section{A test} 
\inmargin{a test}adjust your margins to accommodate the type.  
\input tufte 
\input zapf    

\section{Another test}

\input knuth   
a test 
\dorecurse{2}{\input zapf \par \input tufte} 
\stoptext
```

[image]

```
\setupcolors[textcolor=red]
\setupinmargin[color=red,style=slanted] 
\starttext 

\section{A test} 
\inmargin{a test} 
\input tufte  
\input zapf      

\section{Another test}  

\input knuth   
a test 
\dorecurse{2}{\input zapf \par \input tufte}  
\stoptext
```

[image]

```
\setupcolors[textcolor=red]
\setupinmargin[line=13,color=red,style=slanted,] 

\starttext 
\section{A test} 
\inmargin{a test}

\input tufte  
\input zapf      

\section{Another test}   
\inmargin{another\\ test}
\input knuth   
a test 

\dorecurse{2}{\input zapf \inmargin{ another\\ test\\ of tests} \par \input tufte}    
\stoptext
```

[image]
[image]

```
\setupcolors[state=start,textcolor=red,]
\setupfootnotes[,conversion=Romannumerals,]
\starttext  
\section{A Test}
\dorecurse{2}{\input zapf \par \startlocalfootnotes Nota \footnote[]{Bene}\stoplocalfootnotes \input tufte}

\placelocalfootnotes
\pagebreak
\dorecurse{2}{\input tufte \par \input zapf}

\stoptext
```

[image]

```
\setupcolors[state=start,textcolor=red]
\setupinmargin[line=23,color=darkgreen,]
\setupfootnotes[color=green]
\starttext

a test\footnote{\red some nonsense text to test it out.}
\dorecurse{4}{\input hawking \footnote{ \darkblue If in 2600 you stacked all the new books being published next to
each other, you would have to move at ninety miles an hour just to
keep up with the end of the line. Of course, by 2600 new artistic
and scientific work will come in electronic forms, rather than as
physical books and paper. Nevertheless, if the exponential growth
continued, there would be ten papers a second in my kind of
theoretical physics, and no time to read them.}}\inright{This artificial \\ Wild West\\ became America's Iliad.}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @doed: `\setupcolors[state=start]` is default for mkiv.

Comment: @Aditya I was using mkii first, which requires it, so if it is mkiv, then color option was omitted in the setup of the margin. So now should I edit the question to specify both mkii and mkiv? When a question about ConTeXt comes up, it usually does not make the distinction which version of ConTeXt is used.

Comment: Rather than using local footnotes, you can also use `\setupfootnotes[color=red]`.

Comment: @Aditya of course, but your specific suggestion `\setupfootnotes[color=red]` won't resolve having footnotes in the same color in the document. Whereas local footnotes will.

Comment: @doed: It should have been `\setupnotation[footnotes]`. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108814/323).

Comment: @Aditya the last above was mkii, `\setupnotation[footnotes]` is an undefined control sequence with it,mult.mkii would confirm it

Comment: @doed: `\setupnotation` is for MkIV. For MkII it should be `\setupnotedefinition`.

Comment: @Aditya was the last a typo? I only have a `\setupfootnotedefinition`, not `\setupnotedefinition`